# Install Comodo SSL on Shiny server

Tags: apache2, ssl, r

I have a ssl certificate from comodo and i want to setup this ssl on my upunto R/Shiny server and i have this files from comodo:

1. STAR_getedara_com.crt
2. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
3. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
4. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

First I added 443 port to my aws server

and i concatenated my all files in one file with:

`cat STAR_getedara_com.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >apache.crt`

and then i gegerated a private key by :

```
openssl genrsa -out /etc/ssl/private/apache.key 2048
```

and then i edited my 000-default.conf file

```
    <VirtualHost *:*>

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache.key
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3838/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3838/
 ServerName bi.getedara.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /log/ "/var/log/"
    <Directory "/var/log/">
           Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Order deny,allow
           Deny from all
           Allow from all
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after that i try to restart apache and i get this error:

> Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details

```
systemctl status apache2.service
```

```

````
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-17 09:18:47 UTC; 2min 54s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1273 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)```
May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: Output of config test was:

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: [Thu May 17 09:18:47.646658 2018] [proxy_html:notice]  [pid 1346] AH01425: I18n support in mod_proxy_html requires mod_xml2enc. Without it, non-ASCII characters

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: SSLCertificateKeyFile: file /etc/ssl/private/myserver.key' does not exist or is empty

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: Action 'configtest' failed.
May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[1273]: The Apache error log may have more information.

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited,code=exited status=1

May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 09:18:47 ip-172-31-18-184 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.```
````

Comment: `May 15 12:17:00 ip-172-31-18-184 apache2[6826]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /etc/apache2/sites-e.....` and following lines should give you a clue. You have cut off the end of the lines, so I can't see the full error or filename.

Comment: @SorenA I'm sorry for that , and thanks for editing.